# Quelle est la nuance entre « Il a des dispositions pour les travaux manuels » et « Il a les dispositions pour les travaux manuels »?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Il a **des** dispositions/aptitudes pour les travaux manuels car il est habile de ses mains.

Il a **les** dispositions/aptitudes pour les travaux manuels car il est habile de ses mains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. *Il a **des** dispositions/aptitudes pour les travaux manuels **car** il est habile de ses mains.*

   Cette phrase signifie qu'il a certaines dispositions pour les travaux manuels et en cite une. C'est un peu malhabile car on n'en cite qu'une. Ce qui serait plus juste est :

   *Il a **au moins une** disposition/aptitude  pour les travaux manuels **car** il est habile de ses mains.*
2. *Il a **les** dispositions/aptitudes pour les travaux manuels car il est habile de ses mains.*

   Cette phrase n'est ni idiomatique, ni logique. Elle sous entend qu'il a **toutes** les dispositions requises pour les travaux manuels (ou éventuellement celles dont on vient de parler) mais cette affirmation est encore moins que précédemment la conséquence du fait qu'il soit habile de ses mains. On pourrait écrire:

   *Il a **les** dispositions **requises** pour les travaux manuels. **En particulier**, il est habile de ses mains.*

Answer (score 2):

On n'utilise pas « avoir les dispositions pour » dans le sens de « avoir toutes les dispositions afférentes à ».

1/ Pour « [a les dispositions](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/M%C3%A9ditations_sur_les_v%C3%A9rit%C3%A9s_de_la_vie/rg6Znx3vp9AC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22a+les+dispositions%22&pg=PA318&printsec=frontcover) » tous les cas d'occurrence dans les livres Google sont des faux positifs sauf un qui date de 1863.
([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/M%C3%A9ditations_sur_les_v%C3%A9rit%C3%A9s_de_la_vie/rg6Znx3vp9AC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22a+les+dispositions%22&pg=PA318&printsec=frontcover))

[image]

1/ « [N'a pas les dispositions](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22n%27a%20pas%20les%20dispositions%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)) » ne se trouve pas du tout.

3/ « [avoir les dispositions](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22avoir%20les%20dispositions%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) » ne se trouve que si « dispositions » est modifié, comme dans le cas suivant. De plus, les cas sont rares et ne se trouvent, sauf un, que dans la première partie du 18<sup>e</sup> siècle.

[image]

4/ « [N'ont pas les dispositions](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22n%27ont%20pas%20les%20dispositions%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)) » ne se trouve pratiquement pas.

On peut remarquer que la plupart des rares cas  se trouvent essentiellement dans la littérture ecclésiastique.

D'après une définition du mot « disposition », « aptitude particulière (à quelque chose). Synon. inclination, prédisposition  ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/disposition)) », puis une définition du mot « aptitude », « Qualité rendant possibles certaines performances » ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aptitude)), on peut dire qu' « avoir les dispositions » signifie foncièrement « avoir **les** qualités rendant certaines performances possibles ».

Il semble qu'il faille conclure que l'usage n'a pas jugé suffisamment exact que l'on puisse référer dans chaque cas à toutes les qualités qui ont trait à la performance donnée, que, les humains  étant voués à n'en connaitre  et surtout à n'en posséder qu'une partie,  il serait apparu suffisant, plus juste, de n'en mentionner qu'un groupe restreint indéfini ; ceci serait la raison pour n'utiliser quasi uniquement que « des ».

Évidemment, si « dispositions » est utilisé avec une modification « les » devient naturel ; néanmoins, ce type d'usage est aussi assez rare.

- ([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Monsieur_%C3%89mery/o-IfEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22dispositions+les+plus+%C3%A9l%C3%A9mentaires%22&pg=PT79&printsec=frontcover)) Certains manquent des dispositions les plus élémentaires ; une haute naissance n'est point toujours garante de vertu.
- ([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Moi_Symmaque/4GBdx-pbpakC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22dispositions+les+plus+%C3%A9l%C3%A9mentaires%22&pg=PA92&printsec=frontcover)) Ils sont liés à la société par les dispositions les plus élémentaires de leur nature